# Mysql complex select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a case which seems very complex to me and I am currently doing it in 3 queries and with lots of application logic. I thought, it may be possible with only one single queries.

I have a three table,

```
1. conversations table 
2. chats table
3. users table
```

Please see the two pictures so that you can see the entities with the actual data.

`conversations table`

[image]

`chats table`

[image]

Please look at the conversation table. Here I want to get all the rows where `sender=1 or reciever=1` so expected results will be 
`id 3,4,5`. Now, I also return the user details from these selected rows.

Here is the most difficult part for me. I don't want to retrieve users details of `id 1` instead I want users details whose  `id are 2,3 and 4 notice 4 in sender column and 2 3 in reciever column`

Now, you know the selected rows from conversations table. In second table, `con_id is the foreign key of conversation table` so I want to retrieve the last rows of each `con_id`. In the second picture, you can see `id 2,3,4,5,6` has `con_id = 3` but since I want the last one so it should select `where id = 6` similarly all last row of each `con_id`

I am sorry for this long case, hope you got me and the problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the sql tables and dummy data for you so that if you want you can test paste quickly

Expected results

```
   id || sender || reciver || id(users id) ||  userName   || id(chats id) || con_id || msg || msg_sender
   3    1          2           2             iamsadek2          6              3      ...      2
   4    1          3           3             sadek3             10             4      ...      3
   5    4          1           4             adek4.             14.            5.     ...      4 








DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chats`;

CREATE TABLE `chats` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msg_sender` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `con_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` text,
  `file` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `con_id` (`con_id`),
  KEY `msg_sender` (`msg_sender`),
  CONSTRAINT `chats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`con_id`) REFERENCES `conversations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `chats_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`msg_sender`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `chats` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `chats` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `chats` (`id`, `msg_sender`, `con_id`, `msg`, `file`, `deleted`, `seen`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (2,1,3,'id 1 sending msg to id 2',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:36:06',NULL),
    (4,2,3,'id 2 sending msg to id 1 second msg',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:36:37',NULL),
    (5,1,3,'id 1 sending msg to id 2 msg 3',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:36:42',NULL),
    (6,2,3,'id 2 sending msg to id 1 msg 4',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:36:46',NULL),
    (7,1,4,'id 1 sending msg to id 3 msg 1',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:36:49',NULL),
    (8,3,4,'id 3 sending msg to id 1 msg 2am',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:39:44',NULL),
    (9,3,4,'id 3 sending msg to id 1 msg 3',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:39:55',NULL),
    (10,3,4,'id 3 sending msg to id 1 msg 4',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:39:57',NULL),
    (11,4,5,'id 4 sending msg to id 1 msg 1',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:40:46',NULL),
    (12,4,5,'id 4 sending msg to id 1 msg 1',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:40:48',NULL),
    (13,4,5,'id 4 sending msg to id 1 msg 3',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:40:50',NULL),
    (14,1,5,'id 1 sending msg to id 4 msg 4',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:41:01',NULL),
    (15,4,11,'id 4 sending msg to id 3 msg 1',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:42:37',NULL),
    (16,3,11,'id 3 sending msg to id 4 msg 2',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:42:57',NULL),
    (17,3,11,'id 3 sending msg to id 4 msg 2',NULL,NULL,0,'2018-06-26 19:42:59',NULL);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `chats` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table conversations
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `conversations`;

CREATE TABLE `conversations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `reciever` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sender` (`sender`),
  KEY `reciever` (`reciever`),
  CONSTRAINT `conversations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sender`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `conversations_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`reciever`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `conversations_reciever_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`reciever`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `conversations_sender_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sender`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `conversations` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `conversations` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `conversations` (`id`, `sender`, `reciever`, `status`, `type`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (3,1,2,0,0,'2018-06-26 19:32:35',NULL),
    (4,1,3,0,0,'2018-06-26 19:32:50',NULL),
    (5,4,1,0,0,'2018-06-26 19:33:11',NULL),
    (6,2,3,0,0,'2018-06-26 19:33:22',NULL),
    (11,3,4,0,0,'2018-06-26 19:33:22',NULL);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `conversations` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;


# Dump of table users
# ------------------------------------------------------------

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profilePic` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'user.png',
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userType` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'User',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(11) DEFAULT 'active',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_username_unique` (`userName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `profilePic`, `address`, `lat`, `lang`, `ip`, `password`, `email`, `userName`, `gender`, `userType`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1,'sadek','hossain','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$ayAJE7BxkgqXPGjVxeD8iu0GVWL6CXJFdLhGcHAN.i39lCqcAR5nS','sadek.hkm@gmail.com','iamsadek','male','User','2018-06-26 18:33:16','2018-06-26 18:33:16','active'),
    (2,'sadek2','hossain2','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$q.LNN48POO9g1INdEC/iTO1CJjGXNBLYZPbHkyRe.oHaZJi9b8GWe','sadek2.hkm@gmail.com','iamsadek2','male','User','2018-06-26 18:42:53','2018-06-26 18:42:53','active'),
    (3,'sadek3','hossain3','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$7xgKQDUw/tA6f8zb0uqSN.z7RnNuUVAoMuB6Eknm/cqzXk7BDcmIi','sadek3@gmail.com','sadek3','male','User','2018-06-26 19:02:30','2018-06-26 19:02:30','active'),
    (4,'sadek3','hossain3','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$7xgKQDUw/tA6f8zb0uqSN.z7RnNuUVAoMuB6Eknm/cqzXk7BDcmIi','sadek4@gmail.com','sadek4','male','User','2018-06-26 19:02:30','2018-06-26 19:02:30','active'),
    (5,'sadek3','hossain3','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$7xgKQDUw/tA6f8zb0uqSN.z7RnNuUVAoMuB6Eknm/cqzXk7BDcmIi','sadek5@gmail.com','sadek5','male','User','2018-06-26 19:02:30','2018-06-26 19:02:30','active'),
    (6,'sadek3','hossain3','user.png',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'$2a$10$7xgKQDUw/tA6f8zb0uqSN.z7RnNuUVAoMuB6Eknm/cqzXk7BDcmIi','sadek6@gmail.com','sadek6','male','User','2018-06-26 19:02:30','2018-06-26 19:02:30','active');

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Nope, I did not get it. Pls provite the expected redults in a tabular format and pls also share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am trying with 3 queries and lots of application level logic to achieve it. 

`const con_ids= await Con.query().where('sender',1).orWhere('reciever',1).orderBy('created_at','desc').select('id')
    //convert ids array
    let ids= []
    for(let d of con_ids){
     ids.push(d.id)
    }

    const listing= await Chat.query().whereIn('con_id', ids).groupBy('con_id').orderBy('created_at', 'desc').fetch()`


Trying to create a tabular way for the expected results.

Comment: Updated the question with expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can basically be done with some joins. The tricky part is the last message for `chats`. The subquery groups the chats by the `con_id` to get the maximum `id`. As `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, the maximum `id` for a `con_id` is the last message of the conversation.

```
SELECT co1.id,
       co1.sender,
       co1.reciever,
       us.id "id(users id)",
       us.username,
       ch1.id "id(chats id)",
       ch1.con_id,
       ch1.msg,
       ch1.msg_sender
       FROM conversations co1
            INNER JOIN users us
                       ON CASE
                            WHEN co1.sender <> 1
                              THEN co1.sender
                            WHEN co1.reciever <> 1
                              THEN co1.reciever
                          END = us.id
            INNER JOIN chats ch1
                       ON ch1.con_id = co1.id
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(ch2.id) id,
                               ch2.con_id
                               FROM chats ch2
                               GROUP BY ch2.con_id) ch3
                       ON ch3.con_id = ch1.con_id
                          AND ch3.id = ch1.id
       WHERE 1 IN (co1.sender,
                   co1.reciever);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93a543/16)

Instead of an `INNER JOIN` with the subquery with the `GROUP BY`, a correlated subyquery would be another option.

```
SELECT co1.id,
       co1.sender,
       co1.reciever,
       us.id "id(users id)",
       us.username,
       ch1.id "id(chats id)",
       ch1.con_id,
       ch1.msg,
       ch1.msg_sender
       FROM conversations co1
            INNER JOIN users us
                       ON CASE
                            WHEN co1.sender <> 1
                              THEN co1.sender
                            WHEN co1.reciever <> 1
                              THEN co1.reciever
                          END = us.id
            INNER JOIN chats ch1
                       ON ch1.con_id = co1.id
       WHERE 1 IN (co1.sender,
                   co1.reciever)
             AND ch1.id = (SELECT max(ch2.id)
                                  FROM chats ch2
                                  WHERE ch2.con_id = co1.id);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93a543/18)

Comment: Works like a charm. :) This will have too much performance effect right?

Comment: @sadek: Check the execution plans for both to find out, can be the first one can be the last one. But I guess it's likely to be faster than the multiple queries in between application logic as you have now.

Comment: Thank you. I found both runs in similar speed. But I will keep both of them. Thank you for such an awesome for such a complex problem.

Comment: HI, disturbing you again, how can I use order by ch1.id desc so that I get most recently created chat first? Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I was able to do in first query but nothing happens in second query. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

TRy it now

```
      SELECT id.conversations, sender.conversations, receiver.conversations, id.users, userName.users, id.chats, con_id.chats, msg.chats, msg_sender.chats
  FROM conversations, chats, users
 WHERE (sender.conversations OR receiver.conversations = 1) AND id.conversations=firstname.users 
    GROUP BY id.conversations
```

Comment: parenthesis because of and/or possibly?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 if you have asked me, then I didn't get you. :)

Comment: Gives error `Unknown column 'id.conversations' in 'field list'`